# ApiAuth gem + ActiveResource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeresource, api-auth

I'm trying to get ApiAuth working with ActiveResource and having no luck. The documentation suggests this as the way to use the gem:

```
class Foo < ActiveResource::Base
  with_api_auth("foo", "bar")
end
```

This results in the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `with_api_auth' for Foo:Class
```

I know that the api_auth library is available because when I do

```
require 'api_auth'
```

i get "false", which I believe means that the library/gem was already loaded.

Additionally, I picked out the module/class where with_api_auth is defined and don't get an error:

```
2.3.8 :004 > 
ApiAuth::Rails::ActiveResourceExtension::ActiveResourceApiAuth
=> ApiAuth::Rails::ActiveResourceExtension::ActiveResourceApiAuth
2.3.8 :005 >
```

I found a couple issues for this exact error on the api_auth github project, but neither had solutions that worked for me.

Anyone else see this error or know how to eliminate it?

Comment: https://github.com/mgomes/api_auth/issues/28
Does this help? What's your Gemfile entry for this?

Comment: No, that didn't fix things for me. However, github.com/mgomes/api_auth/issues/113 did actually send me down the right path. I'm putting up my solution as the answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

So in the end it was an ordering of gems in my Gemfile that made the difference. It ended up being an ordering issue in my Gemfile. I found an [issue (113)](https://github.com/mgomes/api_auth/issues/113) on the gem github issues list that said to make sure the order was right by doing:

```
gem 'activeresource'
gem 'api-auth'
```

Originally this hadn't worked and it ended up being because you no longer have to explicitly put activeresource in your Gemfile. So I moved `gem 'api-auth'` the last line in my Gemfile and everything worked.

I don't know for sure, but I think it has to do with how mixins are loaded on bundle install. "think" being the most important word in that statement.

Comment: yeah, you're right active resource needs to be loaded first in the Rails environment in order to register api auth with active resource. Check this out https://github.com/mgomes/api_auth/blob/master/lib/api_auth/railtie.rb#L81, you'll find that api auth is looking for active resource and registering the api auth extensions with active resource.